# How to link a header in a standards-compliant way?

Tags: html, css, standards, w3c

I have a block of HTML that looks like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <h2>subtitle</h2>
</div>
```

I'm using a CSS technique to hide all that text and replace it with an image. But I want to link the whole block to the homepage. I can't wrap it in `<a>` because that wouldn't be standards-compliant. So how do I do it?

---

My solution; inspired by [New in town](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151323/new-in-town)

```
<div id="header">   
    <h1>title</h1>
    <h2>subtitle</h2>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
</div>

#header {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 384px;
    height: 76px;
    background: transparent url(../images/header.png) no-repeat;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#header a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a link element outside of the header divs and make it cover them by using the absolute positioning. Also add a z-index to make sure the link receives user input.

```
<style>
    a.header
    {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>

<div id="header">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h2>subtitle</h2>
</div>

<a href="homepage" class="header"></a>
```

Comment: I guess the idea's good, but I think your semantics are wrong. There should be text inside the `<a>` tag, and it's probably easier to work with if you toss the `<a>` in the header too.

Answer (score 0):

Overlay a completely transparent image on top of it all that is linked to the homepage?